# How to check if jQuery Globalize is initialized?

Tags: javascript, jquery, globalization, jquery-globalization

I am using the [jQuery Globalize](https://github.com/jquery/globalize) library which uses cldr for internationalization. Before you can use any of the Globalize functions, you have to load the correct cldr-data and pass it to Globalize.

**Is there a way to check if this initialization has already happened and Globalize is ready for use?**

I have some code that is executed on each $(document).ajaxComplete() and I need to make sure some of it only runs after Globalize is ready.

Answer (score 0):

Old issue, but i found that checking the cldr value did it for me:

```
if (Globalize.cldr != null)
{
    ...
}
```